# Problem with amsmath+fontspec+ulem

Tags: xetex, amsmath, fontspec, ulem

I have a problem when I tried to compile this using XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem,amsmath,fontspec}

\begin{document}
\[1+1=2\]
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try loading `fontspec` before `ulem`.

Comment: @Francis you should write an answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I know there are conflicts, but I don't know what caused them exactly.

Comment: The conflict seems to be in the redefinition of ``\\`` made by `ulem`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Maybe you shouldn't remove `amsmath` tag? This problem appears only if you load all three package together.

Comment: @Francis -- i added it back.  maybe you can make it clear (in the answer you were requested to write) why it's involved.  thanks.

Comment: @egreg -- the problem (not specified in question) seems to be that the job hangs.  i'm not well versed in the innards of either `ulem` or `fontspec`, but tried out all combinations with the trivial example given.  it only hangs if `fontspec` is last; if `fontspec` is *not* last, the three packages can be in any order.  so the problem may be a little more complicated than you noted.  any other suggestions?

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was quite puzzling, but finally I got it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `ulem` is loaded before `amsmath` and `fontspec`, the definition of `\[` results being

```
> \[=macro:
->\protect \[  .
```

instead of the correct one

```
> \[=macro:
->\x@protect \[\protect \[  .
```

as defined by `amsmath` via `\DeclareRobustCommand.

The problem is due to the fact that `ulem` defines `\MakeRobust`; later `fontspec` loads `fixltx2e` that does `\providecommand\MakeRobust[1]{...}` and then `\MakeRobust\[`; so, instead of using the good definition of `fixltx2e`, the faulty version provided by `ulem` is used.

This should be considered as a bug in `ulem`: the package should load `fixltx2e` and use its version of `\MakeRobust`.

Loading `ulem` after `fontspec` somewhat cures the problem, but leaves in memory the bad definition of `\MakeRobust`, which could have effects if some later loaded package relies on `fixltx2e` version of `\MakeRobust`.

Perhaps, a better solution is to do

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\let\MakeRobust\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

so that the faulty `\MakeRobust` is only used for `ulem`'s purposes (which work) and then removed from memory, so that `fixltx2e` can give the good definition.

Comment: great sleuthing!